# get_dummies usage in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a book on Introduction to machine learning using Python. Here authors described as below
Let’s say for the workclass feature we have possible values of "Government
Employee", "Private Employee", "Self Employed" and "Self Employed Incorpora
ted".

```
print("Original features:\n", list(data.columns), "\n")

data_dummies = pd.get_dummies(data)

print("Features after get_dummies:\n", list(data_dummies.columns))

Original features:
['age', 'workclass']

Features after get_dummies:
['age', 'workclass_ ?', 'workclass_ Government Employee', 'workclass_Private Employee', 'workclass_Self Employed', 'workclass_Self Employed Incorporated']
```

My question is what is new column workclass_ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is created with string values of column `workclass`:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'age':[1,1,1,2,1,1],
                   'workclass':['Government Employee','Private Employee','Self Employed','Self Employed Incorpora ted','Self Employed Incorpora ted','?']})

print (data)
   age                    workclass
0    1          Government Employee
1    1             Private Employee
2    1                Self Employed
3    2  Self Employed Incorpora ted
4    1  Self Employed Incorpora ted
5    1                            ?
```

---

```
data_dummies = pd.get_dummies(data)
print (data_dummies)
   age  workclass_?  workclass_Government Employee  \
0    1            0                              1   
1    1            0                              0   
2    1            0                              0   
3    2            0                              0   
4    1            0                              0   
5    1            1                              0   

   workclass_Private Employee  workclass_Self Employed  \
0                           0                        0   
1                           1                        0   
2                           0                        1   
3                           0                        0   
4                           0                        0   
5                           0                        0   

   workclass_Self Employed Incorpora ted  
0                                      0  
1                                      0  
2                                      0  
3                                      1  
4                                      1  
5                                      0
```

And if have multiple columns with same values this prefix is really helpfull:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'age':[1,1,3],
                   'workclass':['Government Employee','Private Employee','?'],
                   'workclass1':['Government Employee','Private Employee','Self Employed']})

print (data)
   age            workclass           workclass1
0    1  Government Employee  Government Employee
1    1     Private Employee     Private Employee
2    3                    ?        Self Employed

data_dummies = pd.get_dummies(data)
print (data_dummies)
   age  workclass_?  workclass_Government Employee  \
0    1            0                              1   
1    1            0                              0   
2    3            1                              0   

   workclass_Private Employee  workclass1_Government Employee  \
0                           0                               1   
1                           1                               0   
2                           0                               0   

   workclass1_Private Employee  workclass1_Self Employed  
0                            0                         0  
1                            1                         0  
2                            0                         1
```

If dont need it, is possible add parameters for overwrite it by empty space:

```
data_dummies = pd.get_dummies(data, prefix='', prefix_sep='')
print (data_dummies)
   age  ?  Government Employee  Private Employee  Government Employee  \
0    1  0                    1                 0                    1   
1    1  0                    0                 1                    0   
2    3  1                    0                 0                    0   

   Private Employee  Self Employed  
0                 0              0  
1                 1              0  
2                 0              1
```

And then is possible `groupby` by columns and aggregate `max` for dummies per unique columns:

```
print (data_dummies.groupby(level=0, axis=1).max())
   ?  Government Employee  Private Employee  Self Employed  age
0  0                    1                 0              0    1
1  0                    0                 1              0    1
2  1                    0                 0              1    3
```

Comment: actually here we are not observing workclass_? but author mentioned that. what is this column

Comment: @Thanks got it now